# How to highlight error if a node property is confused with function and vise versa. e.g. Show errors for `node.innerText()` or `node.toLowerCase`

Tags: javascript, eslint

When writing javascript what is the best way to tell or highlight if I've treated a property as a function or a function as a property.

e.g. How can I highlight these as errors `node.innerText()` or `node.toLowerCase`.

I'm using vscode and eslint but I can't figure out what settings or even if I can make the above show up as errors.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a `try catch` block

```
try {
//your code
} catch (error){
console.error(error)
}
```

or just simply `console.error(value)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use typescript to catch most of these bugs at “compile” time.

They are two major ways. Add `//@ts-check` at the start it the JS file, or set up tsconfing and all that goes along.

Comment: Thanks that does exactly what I want.